# Select By Location and Calculate the Field Attributes Using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, cursor

I want to create a ModelBuilder tool that I can use to save my time when I need to populate a ward name into my asset layers.

Here Ward is a Polygon feature layer and my asset layers can be point, line or polygon. Ward polygon layer has 14 different wards in my selected area and the asset layers (point, line, polygon) are distributed randomly everywhere in those wards.

I'm relatively new to ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro.

I don't want to create a new dataset, I want to update the existing enterprise geodatabase feature class using SelectByLocation method.

My script looks like as below;

```
pts = "E:\Map Documents\DATABASE CONNECTIONS - SQL SERVER\Default.gdb\British_National_Grid\BL_Bollard" 
poly = "E:\Map Documents\DATABASE CONNECTIONS - SQL SERVER\Portsmouth.sde\Portsmouth.DBO.Road_Network\Portsmouth.DBO.PortsmouthWards"
fieldname = "ElectoralWard"
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(pts, "INTERSECT", poly, None, "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pts,fieldname) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "Hilsea"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

It works very well but populate the single value "Hilsea" in all rows. I don't know how to use if/elif class.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm

Answer (score 0):

A single tool could copy the Ward name into your asset layer but it creates a new dataset, explore the Spatial Join tool, so no need for using model builder.

Answer (score 0):

If your assets are not contained inside one single ward, and you want to split your assets along the ward limits, you can also look into the [Intersect](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool.
Just like [Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm), it will create a new dataset.